# Best image format when vectorized doesn't cut it

Tags: graphics, png, performance, pixelated

So I have what I think is a pretty unusual usecase, which is why I made a new question for this. I have an image I want to include in a document which is a big noisy scatterplot. If I save it as a (pdf) vector image, it is very big due to all these random datapoints that need to be drawn.

What I care about minimizing are the final document filesize, since it needs to be sent around, and compile time, since I want to iterate quickly. The images themselves will just live in my own storage, so I don't care about their size.

To reduce the size of the images in the document, I was thinking of rasterizing them, choosing a relatively (but not unnecessarily) high DPI value such that you don't see the difference unless you really try to zoom in. Now I've heard PNG has quite a big impact on latex compile or render time, since it needs to be decompressed. So what I thought of doing was to use BMP, which is, as far as I know, completely uncompressed. This will make the original image files larger, but as I said I don't care about that since it's just space on my harddrive.

Am I correct in assuming bmp will be quicker to render because it is uncompressed? Should I be doing something else instead?

EDIT: to give a sense of scale, the image in question is a scatter plot with at this time about 30 thousand (semitransparent) datapoints, which, as a standalone image, results in a 1.5MB pdf file, and when added into the latex document, adds about 1.5 MB to a file which is at this point around 2.5MB, turning it into 4.0MB. Obviously none of those sizes are particularly large right now, but it might become a problem if I add a bunch more comparable images.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your question? Also please indicate size somehow, e.g. the number of data points (order of magnitude), the pdf's file size etc.

Comment: Sure, one sec. What would you like a screenshot of?

Comment: Anything you feel relevant, AND so I can see what you mean by "a big noisy scatterplot".

Comment: You can use PNG and then convert the bitmap to PDF, then the LaTeX process does not have to reconvert it.

Comment: Actually that might be a good idea to try.

Comment: FWIK `jpeg` format can be embedded almost natively in PDF, and if you choose a sufficiently high quality you can have a basically indistinguishable quality at least at screen or normal print size. And the jpeg will be quite smaller...

Comment: bmp will not help as pdf does not support it,you can use jpg or pdf (or png as pdftex includes a png to pdf conversion)

Comment: What happened to your informative screenshot?